# Cannot get pandas tabular data from json to csv and back from dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I hope I do this right. I'm a first time poster. 
I have a pandas json-csv data-frame problem, and have been looking for solutions for a few days now. It may be small and obvious error, but I have tried may examples. Here is my code:

```
print('__Trades__' '\n')
    since = int(time.time()*1000)-24*60*60*1000
    xbtzartrades = c.list_trades(pair='XBTZAR', since=since)
    exctrades = (xbtzartrades)
    json_object = json.dumps(exctrades, indent=4)  # Serializing json
    with open("exdata/json/xbtzartrades.json", "w") as outfile:    #  Open a file in exdata/json/
        outfile.write(json_object)  # Writing to json
    df = pd.read_json("exdata/json/xbtzartrades.json")   # read the json file
    df.to_csv(r'exdata/csv/xbtzartrades.csv', index=None)
    #  print(df)   #  Print the contents of df
    #  print(xbtzartrades)    #  Print the recent trades.
```

Output to exdata/json/xbtzartrades.json:

```
{
    "trades": [
        {
            "sequence": 7933159,
            "timestamp": 1586191458641,
            "price": "139449.00",
            "volume": "0.001444",
            "is_buy": false
        },
        {
            "sequence": 7933158,
            "timestamp": 1586191450810,
            "price": "139449.00",
            "volume": "0.001122",
            "is_buy": false
        },  ------------> ECT.
```

Instead of a tabular format. The CSV file ends up like this:

```
trades
"{'sequence': 7933159, 'timestamp': 1586191458641, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.001444', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933158, 'timestamp': 1586191450810, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.001122', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933157, 'timestamp': 1586191450695, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.003657', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933156, 'timestamp': 1586191446474, 'price': '139450.00', 'volume': '0.004181', 'is_buy': True}"
"{'sequence': 7933155, 'timestamp': 1586191438571, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.005716', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933154, 'timestamp': 1586191421319, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.001918', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933153, 'timestamp': 1586191420238, 'price': '139449.00', 'volume': '0.007831', 'is_buy': False}"
"{'sequence': 7933152, 'timestamp': 1586191420180, 'price': '139450.00', 'volume': '0.000954', 'is_buy': True}"
```

Comment: Later I need the output to merge with with previous log as this is updated from the server every 20 to 30 seconds. Then the true and false events must be slip from one another. These are the trades that has occurred in an crypto exchange server.

Comment: So, if exctrades is already a dict, why not just create the dataframe from the list of dict in exctrades['trades']?

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm still a noob with python and pandas. Would you be so kind as to give a sample. I'm unfamiliar with dicts and so on.

Comment: Ok found it. I removed this line: since = int(time.time()*1000)-24*60*60*1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `xbtzartrades` has the data you need. It doesn't seem like you need to go through all of the intermediate steps of converting to JSON and then reading a file into pandas.

```
xbtzartrades = c.list_trades(pair='XBTZAR', since=since)
df = pd.DataFrame(xbtzartrades['trades'])
df.to_csv('exdata/csv/xbtzartrades.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. You are a genius!  At the time that was the easiest way I could store the data and then reuse it. I will have to aply this in a few other instances now, but it will make my code shorter.

Comment: There is one more problem Eric. This file 'df.to_csv('exdata/csv/xbtzartrades.csv', index=None)' must be overwritten every time. But it does not do that. Else everything is Kk. The script runs ever 20 or 30 seconds and the data changes all the time.

Answer (score 0):

So my output is correct now:

```
sequence,timestamp,price,volume,is_buy
7933537,1586195229592,139689.00,0.071588,False
7933536,1586195229533,139689.00,0.064388,False
7933535,1586195229515,139689.00,0.0072,False
7933534,1586195228302,139689.00,0.164651,False
```